# iPhone configuration utility failed to locate 'Apple Mobile Device Support'

Tags: ios, iphone, marmalade

I am currently using the Marmalade SDK on my Windows machine to build an app. I am trying to test the app on an iPhone, and downloaded the iPhone Configuration Utility in order to do so. However, whenever I launch it, I get the following error:

iPhone configuration utility failed to locate 'Apple Mobile Device Support'. Please Reinstall the iPhone Configuration Utility. You can download the iPhone configuration Utility from http:://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise.

However, even when I re-install it, I keep getting the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the answer on one of the Apple forums.
It is recent problem for those running 64-bit Windows and updated iTunes to latest 12.1 version.

This iTunes version replaces 32-bit Apple Mobile Device Support with 64-bit version which iPCU doesn't support as it is 32-bit.

The way to resolve it is:

1. Uninstall Apple Mobile Device Support and Apple Application Support via Windows control panel.
2. Download iPhone Configuration Utility and **extract** it using 7-zip
3. Install AppleApplicationSupport.msi and AppleMobileDeviceSupport64.msi (don't mind the 64, it's just installer that is 64-bit, binaries are 32-bit)

Screenshot for your convience
[image]

**Note:** If you still have to use iTunes, you'll have to use 12.01 version until lazy asses from apple fix that.

Edit: Apparently they are not lazy but selfish pricks. iPCU does not exist anymore. It was replaced with Apple Configurator which was not released for Windows.

Comment: I had to install the `AppleApplicationSupport.msi` too otherwise the service does not start.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart Apple Mobile Device service http://support.apple.com/en-en/HT203188

Comment: It appears as though that did not work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Uninstall just the Apple Mobile Device Support
2. Extract  `iPhone Configuration Utility` with any zip utility
3. Install only `AppleMobileDeviceSupport64.msi` ( because other one will not install)